# Enable/Disable shipping methods based on postcode entry?

Tags: shipping, validation

I've seen the tablerate shipping method work based on a CSV with postcode entries.

My question is, can that similar process be used to enable or disable actual shipping methods based on postcode entry?

It can do it for country out of the box, so I reckon it wouldn't be much to change it to postcode and read from a CSV would it?

The website is viewable at www.asg.co.uk/gadgetclinic.

Can anyone help me please? Someone must have some knowledge on this, it seems quite a trivial thing to do...

Comment: what do you mean by "disable" do you want to show only certain shipping methods for certain postcodes? or disable the entire shipping method step from the checkout for certain pincodes?

Comment: Pretty much the same process that happens when the shipping country is selected (in the backend for each shipping method, you can select which country is available for that method). If the country isn't selected, the shipping method is disabled (and put into disabled state). I basically want to move this validation from the country field to the postcode field.. and have the postcodes read from a CSV file.

Comment: Hello? Have you any ideas?

Comment: If you go onto the site and go to ake an order, and hcange the country from UK to something else, you'll see what I want to happen. I want this to work with postcodes from a CSV file.

Comment: Sorry! I have changed shipping costs with given postcodes, but haven't enabled/disabled shipping methods. you need to first find how to enable or disable the shipping methods on the go (like it is done by default magento) and do the same in your  observer which observes the `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_saveShipping` event. I'll post the code if i find time today.

Comment: I appreciate that... I got lost when you mentioned observer haha (I assume that means inspect element.. kinda thing?I'll spend some time seeing if I can learn anything today. I appreciate your help, thanks very much!

Comment: Hi, did you manage to look at this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/webshopapps-matrixrate-1-multiple-table-rates-extension-certified-bug-free.html extension in my project to apply shipping rate according to zip code.

Hope it will help you

Comment: Great extension, works very well

Comment: I used it long ago! How did i forget it??? That was a clean extension and could help.

Comment: I can't see how it can enable/disable shipping methods based on location thoguh.. doesn't it just do the same as the tablerate method?